# How to use express.json and express.raw together?

Tags: node.js, express

I am building a web application with a login form and stripe subscription functionality.

In order to receive JSON data I am using `express.json` as

```
app.use(express.json());
```

When I was using the above middleware to receive `stripe webhook secret` the server could not receive it.

So I had to add the `express.raw`

My middleware looked like this:

```
app.use(express.raw({ type: "application/json" }));
app.use(express.json());
```

But now I am unable to receive form JSON data.

Here is my stripe logic:

```
export const postStripeWebhook = async (req: ExtendedRequest, res: Response) => {
    let data;
    let eventType;
    let event = req.body;
    const webhookSecret = "web hook secret provided by stripe";
    if (webhookSecret) {
        let signature = req.headers["stripe-signature"];

        try {
            event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.body, signature , webhookSecret);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(`⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed.`);  //This part is throwing the error
            return res.sendStatus(400);
        }
        
        data = event.data;
        eventType = event.type;
    } else {
       
       
        data = req.body.data;
        eventType = req.body.type;
    }
    let subscription;

    switch (eventType) {
         
       // Here webhook events are managed

    }

    res.sendStatus(200);
};
```

Here is the index.js code:

```
app.use(express.raw({ type: "application/json" }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

app.post("/webhooks", postStripeWebhook);
```

Updated code-------------------------

index.js:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

app.post("/webhooks", postStripeWebhook);
```

Middleware code:

```
export const postStripeWebhook = async (req: ExtendedRequest, res: Response) => {
    let data;
    let eventType;
    let event = req.body;
    const webhookSecret = "web hook secret provided by stripe";
    if (webhookSecret) {
        let signature = req.headers["stripe-signature"];

        try {
            event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(JSON.stringify(req.body), signature , webhookSecret);     //updated this line
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(`⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed.`);  //This part is throwing the error
            return res.sendStatus(400);
        }
        
        data = event.data;
        eventType = event.type;
    } else {
       
       
        data = req.body.data;
        eventType = req.body.type;
    }
    let subscription;

    switch (eventType) {
         
       // Here webhook events are managed

    }

    res.sendStatus(200);
};
```

I updated the code but still, but the problem persists.

Please guide me on how to modify my middleware to receive both types of data.

Comment: I am getting an error as ``` Webhook signature verification failed.``` when i only use ```app.use(express.json());```

Comment: Should I add to my question or share you privately?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the other routes in my application required `express.json` and only `/webhooks` route required `express.raw` so I bypassed `/wbhooks` route from using `express.json`

Here is how I did it:

index.js

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.originalUrl === "/webhooks") {
        next();
    } else {
        express.json()(req, res, next);
    }
});

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

app.post("/webhooks", express.raw({ type: "application/json" }), postStripeWebhook);
```

Comment: This worked for me. Here's a little more concise solution:

```app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    if (req.originalUrl === "/webhooks/stripe") {
        express.raw({type: "application/json"})(req, res, next)
    } else {
        express.json()(req, res, next);
    }
})```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs

you can add the `bodyParser.json()` as a middleware in your api

For example:
app.post('/some/special/route/accepts_as_json', bodyParser.json() , (req,res)=>{} )

Then leave the `app.use(express.raw({ type: "application/json" }));` on your index, if you don't mention the middleware it will be raw, if you do mention is you will receive the jsons

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `express.raw`, only `express.json`. This parses JSON requests and stores the resulting Javascript object in `req.body`. However, if you want to send this object to `stripe.webhooks.constructEvent`, you must stringify it again:

```js
stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(JSON.stringify(req.body), sig, endpointSecret)
```

Without the `JSON.stringify`, you would send `[object Object]`, which is not understood by Stripe and leads to the observed error.

`express.raw({type: "application/json"})` writes the JSON to `req.body` as a string, but this is not useful except for your special case, therefore I would not use it. However, if the Stripe signature depends on the exact string format of the JSON payload (which I would find strange), then you cannot avoid this. In this case, you should follow Ibrahim shamma's suggestion but put the Stripe middleware *before* the `express.json()`:

```js
app.use(cors());
app.post("/webhooks", express.raw({type: "application/json"}), postStripeWebhook);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

This ensures that the "raw parsing" happens only for `POST /webhooks` requests, all others can still be parsed as normal JSON.

Comment: I tried your answer but still the error persists

Comment: Please see the last suggestion I have added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I tried your suggestion but the problem still persisted. I have found the solution to my problem and posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

you can put `express.raw()` as middleware in your route
like this

```
// Checkout webhook
app.post(
    '/webhook-checkout',
    express.raw({ type: 'application/json' }),
    webhookCheckout
  );

//Middlewares
// to parse or convert body that came from the req from string to json to make it easy to dell with
app.use(express.json())
```